# Synaptic package manager is missing

Tags: 11.10, apt, synaptic

There is no synaptic package manager in 11.10,how should i completely remove(Purge) an installed application?

Does clicking on "install" on any software in Ubuntu Software centre means that the command

```
sudo apt-get install XXXXXXX
```

will be used in the background?

Comment: It is not missing. It was decided to be removed for several reasons mentioned here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/69170/why-was-synaptic-packet-manager-removed-from-the-latest-ubuntu-11-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always install Synaptic from Ubuntu Software Center. From there, you can purge.

`sudo apt-get purge` will also do the trick from the command line. See `man apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

You can still install Synaptic. Otherwise, install `aptitude` and then do

```
sudo aptitude remove package_
```

Notice the underscore at the end. You might also be able to do this with `apt-get`, but I don't have time at the moment to check it out.