# Why Ubuntu is not Installing 'Synaptic Package Manager' as default when installing it on the hard drive?

Tags: package-management, synaptic

I always ask my self about this, and I would really like to know why.

I mean Synaptic is on **EVERY** Ubuntu user's launcher and I know it, that is because it is important.

Why do I and every Ubuntu user have to install it after installing Ubuntu manually ?

Can't Ubuntu does it for us **automatically** ?

Comment: Although I am happy you like synaptic, I do as well, it has not been the default for quite some time now because the ubuntu developers consider it to be a superior tool. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter for a detailed discussion and justification.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Synaptic became obsolete as a graphical tool for "apt" when it got replaced by Ubuntu Software Center.

> I mean Synaptic is on EVERY Ubuntu user's launcher

You probably overestimate the usage of Synaptic. On none of my and none of the computers I maintain Synaptic is installed and I know not a lot of people that use it. So "every" is not correct and I probably would claim less than 5% of all computers using Ubuntu have it installed.

Comment: 5% !!! and how does the rest of Ubuntu users manage packages ?

Comment: They use Ubuntu Software Center or (like me) command line.

Comment: No need to learn terminal, Ubuntu Software Center is very good for the major usage.

Comment: Yeah but I do install software from the internet, and the only way to remove it is by using the terminal (some times with the WINE uninstaller), until now I could not uninstall a software called (BricsCAD V15) and I am really confused about what to do.

Comment: @skonsoft Keyword "major usage" or shall I say "simple tasks".

Comment: @rbaleksandar for simple tasks :)

Answer (score 5):

It's not a default package. That's the technical reason.

The [rationale behind that](https://askubuntu.com/a/69185/449) is all down to the Ubuntu project leadership. They think the Software Centre more than good enough a replacement (it does *do* things Synaptic can't) and thought continuing to have two was confusing.

FWIW, I haven't had Synaptic for years, and I'm still alive.

*Most* people use what they're given; the Software Centre in this case. And when that stops working, tools like `apt-get` and `dpkg` prove themselves more powerful than any GUI, even Synaptic.

Comment: "it does do things Synaptic can't" Like what? Hang while updating the package cache? Crashing? Or the shop for paid applications? LOL Yeah, sure...Synaptic is much more advanced than USC however it is a more user-unfriendly way for package administration. It can not only do what USC can (except for the package synchronization which I haven't tested yet) but it can also do things like backing up packages, generating scripts for automatic installation etc.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're arguing. I've just explained why it was replaced. If you don't like it, make it better or use something else.

Comment: Please provide a list of what USC has that Synaptic doesn't instead of just posting (quote) "it does do things Synaptic can't". True that I've expressed myself in a passionate manner however a more detailed answer in that aspect should be provided.